# Add column identifying original data frame when using pd.concat

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dictionary of data frames like the following:

```
test = {'df1':pd.DataFrame({'col1':[3, 5, 1, 4], 'col2':[3, 5, 1, 4]}), 'df2':pd.DataFrame({'col1':[3, 5, 1, 4], 'col2':[3, 5, 1, 4]}), 'df3':pd.DataFrame({'col1':[3, 5, 1, 4], 'col2':[3, 5, 1, 4]}), 'df4':pd.DataFrame({'col1':[3, 5, 1, 4], 'col2':[3, 5, 1, 4]})]
```

I want to concatenate these data frames, but add a new column which gives 'identity' (dictionary key name) of which data frame the value came from. How can this be done? If I do `pd.concat(test.values())`, I get the concatenation which I want but no identity column.

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `concat` with `keys`

```
pd.concat(test.values(),keys=test.keys())
Out[261]: 
       col1  col2
df1 0     3     3
    1     5     5
    2     1     1
    3     4     4
df2 0     3     3
    1     5     5
    2     1     1
    3     4     4
df3 0     3     3
    1     5     5
    2     1     1
    3     4     4
df4 0     3     3
    1     5     5
    2     1     1
    3     4     4
```

Comment: And, how to get `test['df1']`   from this output?

Comment: `pd.concat(test.values(),keys=test.keys()).loc['df1']` @astro123

Comment: @astro123 if this is what you need , would you like accept ?

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to use `assign`. You can iterate through all `dfs` in your dictionary, and assign the `identity` column as you go:

```
pd.concat([df.assign(identity=k) for k,df in test.items()])
```

Which gives you:

```
   col1  col2 identity
0     3     3      df1
1     5     5      df1
2     1     1      df1
3     4     4      df1
0     3     3      df2
1     5     5      df2
2     1     1      df2
3     4     4      df2
0     3     3      df3
1     5     5      df3
2     1     1      df3
3     4     4      df3
0     3     3      df4
1     5     5      df4
2     1     1      df4
3     4     4      df4
```